# Disable "Priveleged user popup" in fedora 8

Tags: fedora, root, gdm

Problem Statement :-  Automatic Login as "root" in fedora 8. I tried with "/etc/gdm/config..."  file . (working in linux)
                                 But in fedora 8  there is a pop up showing " Please login as normal user ........"

Is there any way of disabling this pop up so that I can get the desktop and start my application without pressing any key.

I know it's a security issue but still i want to do it.

Comment: Fedora 8?! That is _long_ discontinued...

Comment: Fedora 8 is ancient: why are you using it?

Comment: Also note that running your desktop as root is *highly* contraindicated. If you don't know how to disable that warning popup, you almost certainly don't know enough to do so responsibly. Set up a regular user with `sudo` permissions and work from there.

Comment: Let me put it this way: Anyone who theoretically knows how to do this *doesn't* do it because they also know that there are *no* good reasons for doing so, and several good reasons for *not* doing it. In fact, all of the reasons I can think of you might have for wanting to do it are terrible ones at best.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to allow root login in gdm configuration,

Edit `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`,

In the `[daemon]` section, add a line `AllowRoot=true`